# Capacitor going to input of op-amp ruining ramp rate

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, amplifier

I have this IC which creates a linear voltage ramp proportional to the input voltage based on the capacitor on the output in parallel to ground. I then have to do some analog computation using op amps. When I connect the output of this IC to an op-amp, the ramp is ruined. Is there any way around this? Thank you for your help.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hint: what *value* capacitor? Try a much larger value.

Answer (score 2):

Your bias voltage to your opamps looks strange.

Remove the capacitors C8 and C9 and connect the negative terminal of the voltage sources to ground. Remember to change the sign of the negative supply to (-), I cannot tell from your diagram if there is a minus sign. Then look at the output. You opamps are floating in the current configuration.

If the capacitors were there for decoupling, then they were placed incorrectly. Either way these are ideal sources so decoupling capacitors won’t have any effect.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you. Once this is on a PCB shouldn't the supplies have decoupling capacitors though? Will I run into the same problem?

Comment: @KieranClifford the supplies in your PCB need decoupling for sure because it needs to have a low impedance at higher frequencies. But your simulation schematic is using **ideal voltage sources**; therefore, their output impedance is 0 and adding capacitors won't do anything in your sims